# Rearrange namespace declaration in every file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm looking for a way to rearrange a string of text that matches a pattern, as well as lowercase everything.

For example, in my codebase I have "app\Services\PropertyTax".  I want to replace this with "Acme\modules\propertytax\services".

There will only ever be two levels after "app", and the order of the newly formatted string will always swapped and lowercased.

app\Entities\HumanResources => Acme\modules\humanresources\entities

etc.

Looking for a way to do this in every file in a specific directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try awk

```
find . -exec gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -F\\ '/app\\.*\\.*/ {print "Acme\\modules\\"tolower($3)"\\"tolower($2)}' {} \;
```

This will replace the files and also stores the backup of the original file with .bak filename suffix.

If you want to delete the backup files

```
find . -regex ".*bak" -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```